# R viewer margins issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

My Rstudio viewer has something wrong with its margins. it produces small margins outputs. I tried

```
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

but it didn't help. the problem is best explained by the following picture

[image]

The code that I want to display on the viewer is

```
ggplot(us_cases, aes(x = myDate, y = totcases, color = totcases)) + geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Total number of cases") +
  theme_bw() + transition_time(myDate)
```

Comment: run `dev.off()` first, then run your code.

Comment: It doesn't help